# Length of countably many intervals

Tags: real-analysis

The following is a proof from my textbook. I have 2 questions, which are in bold.

**Theorem:** Let $(I_n)$ and $(J_k)$ be sequences of intervals such that $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty I_n=\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty J_k$. If the $I_n$ are pairwise disjoint, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\ell(I_n)\le\sum_{k=1}^\infty\ell(J_k)$. Thus, if the $J_k$ are also pairwise disjoint, then the two sums are equal.

**Proof:**

Suppose, to the contrary, that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\ell(I_n)>\sum_{k=1}^\infty\ell(J_k)$.

Then, for some $N$, we must have $\sum_{n=1}^N\ell(I_n)>\sum_{k=1}^\infty\ell(J_k)$ .

Of course, we also have $\bigcup_{n=1}^N I_n\subset\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty J_k$ .

But now, by expanding each $J_k$ slightly and shrinking each $I_n$ slightly, we may suppose that the $J_k$ are open and the $I_n$ are closed. **This does not seem like a valid mathematical step to me. In a proof, are we allowed to change the question? Please help.**

Thus, the $J_k$ form an open cover for the compact set $\bigcup_{n=1}^N I_n$.

And here is the contradiction: Since we have $\sum_{n=1}^N\ell(I_n)>\sum_{k=1}^M\ell(J_k)$, for any $M$, the sets ($J_k$) form an open cover for  that admits no finite subcover. **Could you please explain this as well?**

Answer (score 1):

This is valid because you have a little bit of room to play with in the inequality. To be explicit, let's suppose that there is a $\gamma > 0$ such that

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{N} |I_n| > \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} |J_k|  + 2\gamma.$$

Replace each $J_k$ with a slightly bigger open set $\tilde{J_k}$, where $|\tilde{J_k}| \le |J_k| + \frac{\gamma}{2^k}$; this can be done explicitly by replacing a (open/closed/semi-open) interval with endpoints $a, b$ by the open interval $(a-\gamma/2^{k + 1}, b + \gamma/2^{k + 1})$.

Carry out a similar (but completely explicit shrinking) process with the $I_n$, getting $\tilde{I_n}$ with $|\tilde{I_n}| \ge |I_n| - \frac{\gamma}{2^n}$. Summing over all $n$ and $k$, you ought to find that

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{N} |\tilde{I_n}| > \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} |\tilde{J_k}|$$

where the new collections have the open/closed properties you were after.

Comment: Thank you so much! Could you answer the 2nd question as well?

Comment: Also, where do we use the fact that the $I_n$ are pairwise disjoint?